# Pull a variable from a specific line in a text file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write to batch files one that will pull the computer info and export it to a text file ie output.txt  I have that one correct.

```
wmic CSProduct get  vendor >> c:\output.txt
wmic CSProduct get  name >> c:\output.txt
```

That gives me an output.txt that contains

Vendor
Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Name
H61N-USB3

Now I need a batch file that will turn lines 2 and 4 into variables.  I have tried

```
set "Name="
for /F "skip=1" %%a in (C:\output.txt) do if not defined Name set "Vend=%%a"
set "Name="
for /F "skip=3" %%b in (C:\output.txt) do if not defined Name set "Name=%%b"

REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OEMInformation /V Model /T REG_SZ /D "Vend, Name" /F
```

But I cannot get it to work.  I am completely new to batch scripts and have no clue what I am doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without the need of a temporary file:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in ('wmic CSProduct get vendor^,name^,version /format:csv') do (
  set vend=%%a
  set name=%%b
)
echo -%vend%-%name%-
```

`wmic` has ugly line endings. There are several ways to trick them out. Here I choosed to use an additional token (that "contains" the line ending), that is not used (Version)

Answer (score 0):

```
set "Vend="
for /F "skip=1" %%a in (C:\output.txt) do if not defined Vend set "Vend=%%a"
set "Name="
for /F "skip=3" %%b in (C:\output.txt) do if not defined Name set "Name=%%b"

echo(%Vend% %Name%
```

If you want the values found for `vend` and `name` in your `reg` line, then use `%vend%` and `%name%`

Essentially, skin #lines, assign the vaue to the correct variable. For each line thereafter, since the variable is then `set`, don't make any assignment.

Ah - you'd probably want the entire line, including spaces.

change `"skip=1"` to `"skip=1delims="`

(change the #skipped to suit)

This assigns the entire line read to the metavariable `%%a` by disabling the delimiters. The default delimiters ar (<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>) so only the first "token" (up to the first delimiter found)  would be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually pretty close.

1. The first `Set "Name="` should have been `Set "Vend="`.
2. The first `for` line should likewise have referred to `not defined Vend` instead of `not defined Name`.
3. If you want delimiters skipped, add `delims=` to read the entire input line. (You can see more details on "for" options by just typing `for /?` at your command line.)
4. In the `reg add` line, the `%%a` and `%%b` should have been the environment variables you created, `%Vend%` and `%Name%` respectively.

So, this should work:

```
set Vend=
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%a in (C:\output.txt) do if not defined Vend set "Vend=%%a"
set Name=
for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%b in (C:\output.txt) do if not defined Name set "Name=%%b"

REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OEMInformation /V Model /T REG_SZ /D "%Vend%, %Name%" /F
```

Answer (score 0):

Stephan is the best solution if you ask me but here is another option.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G IN ('wmic CSProduct get  vendor /value ^|find /i "vendor"') do SET %%G=%%H
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G IN ('wmic CSProduct get  name /value ^|find /i "name"') do SET %%G=%%H
echo %Vendor% %Name%
```